# CORS: NestJs Inside a Azure WebApp Docker Container, CORS denied

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service, nestjs

Im currently trying to deploy my NestJs App on an Azure WebApp Docker Container.

When my frontend (deployed on azure) hits the backend api, I get a CORS error.
I added the frontend URL to the CORS allowed origins inside the azure portal, but still no luck.

I have also tried to enable CORS on the NestJs Bootstrap Phase with

```js
app.enableCors()
```

but it didn't change.

The pre-flight headers do not contain any allowed origin header.
I don't know what Im missing at this point.

Comment: Hi @don, Can you specify your frontend URL that which protocol you are using (HTTP or HTTPS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- CORS requires the browser to send a pre-flight request (OPTIONS) to the server before making the actual request. The browser will stop the future request and issue a CORS error if the pre-flight request encounters an error.
- I hope you have installed the `@nestjs/common` package and import the `CorsMiddleware`

Here is my `main.ts.` file:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CorsOptions } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
    origin: 'https://sampleproject.com',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    preflightContinue: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    credentials: true,
  };
  app.use('/api', CorsMiddleware(corsOptions));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

As a temporary debugging measure, you can try setting the CORS headers explicitly in your NestJS application's middleware or interceptor.

- Add Headers to the backend API Response :

```js
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CorsMiddleware } from './cors.middleware';

@Module({})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(CorsMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class CorsMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'YOUR_FRONTEND_URL');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  }
}
```

Allowed origins, methods, and headers to make sure they align with your frontend's requirements.